# 3 column select into a 2 table column, 1 to many relationship, SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select statement that joins to 2 tables where there ledger transactions and custody transactions.

the select statment joins 3 transactions together

1 ledger (£10) ID XX

1 statement (£8) ID YY

1 statement (£8) ID ZZ

The select statement returns the values so that ID return a single row

```
XX YY ZZ
```

I want to insert these values into my matched transactions table so that they enter my matched table like this

```
Ledger ID    CustodyID
XX YY
XX ZZ
```

here is the sQL select statement

```
select
        LedgerTransactions.HeliumTransID,
        tc1.HeliumTransID,
        tc2.HeliumTransID
    from
        LedgerTransactions
    join StatementTransactions tc1 on
        LedgerTransactions.Acc = tc1.Acc
    and LedgerTransactions.Curr = tc1.Curr
    join StatementTransactions tc2 on
        LedgerTransactions.Acc = tc2.Acc 
    and LedgerTransactions.Curr = tc2.Curr
    where
        abs(LedgerTransactions.SettleAmt - (tc1.SettleAmt + tc2.SettleAmt)) = 0 
    and tc1.HeliumTransID <> tc2.HeliumTransID 
    and (tc1.SettleAmt <= tc2.SettleAmt)
```

Please advise.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Your query refers to three tables and at least four columns, but your sample data has only three.

Comment: Hi guys,
using microsoft sql server management studio. 

I only need the ID's where they account (acc) and the (curr) matches. these ID's will be moved to a new table.

Comment: We need sample data MC, if not we will be guessing!

Comment: I suspect you would want to pivot your select statement and merge it to the table.

Comment: You know how to transpose using the techniques in your previous question. You can apply them here or learn and use an actual pivot.

Comment: how do i attach?